# Shipping price for different countries using Commerce Kickstart

Tags: commerce

I'm using [commerce_kickstart](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) distribution.

I need to set different prices for shipping products to different countries.
Ex: France -> 10€, Spain -> 15€...

I guess I have to create a rule at: admin/commerce/config/shipping/calculation-rules but I don't know to create a condition to check over the selected Country in the Shipping Information filled by the buyer.

I think I saw a video about this at http://vimeo.com/31586256 but i can't find it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy solution is to create multiple flat rate shipping methods. As each of them is create as a rule, you can add different conditions to them, being the value of the contry in the shipping address.

Commerce shipping with then only present the user for the flat rate shipping that has the correct contry, and the price you setup will then be applied.

Comment: It worked, just by adding the address comparasion condition.