# How to limit and enable Commerce shipping options based on the customer's country?

Tags: 7, commerce, rules

Very simple use case, using only flat rate shipping, with version 2 of [Drupal Commerce Shipping](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping) and [Drupal Commerce Flat Rate](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_flat_rate). I have two shipping options customers can choose between if they are in one country (the UK) and two if they're in any other country. Let's call them:

- UK standard
- UK special
- International standard
- International special

I've looked for ways to switch shipping rates on and off using rules, but all I can find is rules that *apply* a particular shipping rate, not rules which enable or disable *options* that the customer can then choose between.

[This related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52514/shipping-price-for-different-countries-using-commerce-kickstart) gives a faint outline of how to *apply* rates, but not how to enable or disable options, and likewise [this related question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/179439/commerce-shipping-by-weight-and-country), where there are 12 options but all are chosen *for* the customer (and the answers simply say "use rules"). Under the Calculation Rules tab under `admin/commerce/config/shipping/services/flat-rate`, I can't see anything in the "actions" list that looks like it enables or disables a particular rate. Plenty that appear to apply a rate, but not giving the customer a choice or limiting the choice.

This is clearly common and possible, as it's [referred to for example in this issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/1230504), but I can't find anything on how to do it.

I've tried adding a rule like this through "Configure component" for a particular shipping rate, but it had no effect, the international rate still appears as an option even if the country is "United Kingdom". Here's the rule:

[image]

Here's another I tried using "Calculation rules" which, also had no effect:

[image]

Everything I can find around enabling or disabling shipping by country is about [disabling countries *completely*](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping_country).

I couldn't find anything in [the Commerce Shipping documentation](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_shipping), and there is no Flat Rate documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The two crucial pieces of information:

- The **"Configure component"** link alongside each shipping rate under `admin/commerce/config/shipping` (Store > Configuration > Shipping) is the place to set validation criteria for a shipping rate to appear as an option.
- In these rules, countries need to be inputted as **two-letter country codes** not the full names.

---

In detail:

- Set up the shipping rates and go to `admin/commerce/config/shipping` (Store > Configuration > Shipping)
- For each one:

  - Follow the "Configure Component" link
  - "Add condition"
  - Commerce Order > Order Address Component Comparison
  - Address value = Shipping Address, Address Component = Country, and tick the Negate box at the very bottom if this is one for "everywhere but" (e.g. international rates)
  - Input the 2-letter country code under Value. You can see what this is by using Inspect Element on a country selector dropdown:

[image]